# Weak limit of a certain measure sequence is stationary

Tags: probability, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I am not very conversant about this topic and was given this question as an assignment. This is my first post so I do apologize if the question is very silly.

Let $\mu$ be any probability measure on a locally compact topological group $G$. Let $\sigma$ be any probability measure on $G$. Then if the sequence of measures $$\frac{1}{n}(\sigma+\mu*\sigma+\cdots+\mu^{n-1}*\sigma)$$ converges to $\nu$ weakly, show that $\nu$ is $\mu$-stationary, i.e. $\mu*\nu=\nu$.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to prove via definition but have not succeeded.

Comment: Write down a relation between $$\frac{1}{n+1}(\sigma+\mu*\sigma+\cdots+\mu^{n-1}*\sigma)$$ and $$\frac{1}{n+1}(\sigma+\mu*\sigma+\cdots+\mu^{n-1}*\sigma+\mu^{n}*\sigma)$$